# What is the complete list of allowable items for the custom recommended items?

Tags: dota-2

I am making some custom recommended item sets for some heroes in Dota 2. What I want is a complete list of what the code for each item is.

If you do not know what I am talking about here is a guide that should provide some more context: [Custom Recommended Items Guide](http://www.dotafire.com/dota-2/guide/custom-recommended-items-63)

An example:

```
Linken's Sphere = item_sphere
Hood of Defiance = item_hood_of_defiance
```

I would like this complete list. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look to file `<Steam>\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\resource\dota_english.txt`, it contains all language definitions.

If you search for `DOTA_Tooltip_Ability_item` you should find a section of items tooltip definitions.

For easy consultation I copy the list here:

```
"item_arcane_ring"          "Arcane Ring"
"item_armlet"               "Armlet"
"item_assault"              "Assault Cuirass"
"item_basher"               "Skull Basher"
"item_belt_of_strength"     "Belt of Strength"
"item_bfury"                "Battle Fury"
"item_black_king_bar"       "Black King Bar"
"item_blade_mail"           "Blade Mail"
"item_blades_of_attack"     "Blades of Attack"
"item_blade_of_alacrity"    "Blade of Alacrity"
"item_blink"                "Blink Dagger"
"item_bloodstone"           "Bloodstone"
"item_boots"                "Boots of Speed"
"item_boots_of_elves"       "Boots of Elvenskin"
"item_bottle"               "Bottle"
"item_bracer"               "Bracer"
"item_branches"             "Iron Branch"
"item_broadsword"           "Broadsword"
"item_buckler"              "Buckler"
"item_butterfly"            "Butterfly"
"item_chainmail"            "Chainmail"
"item_circlet"              "Circlet"
"item_clarity"              "Clarity"
"item_claymore"             "Claymore"
"item_cloak"                "Cloak"
"item_courier"              "Animal Courier"
"item_flying_courier"       "Flying Courier"
"item_cyclone"              "Eul's Scepter of Divinity"
"item_dagon"                "Dagon"
"item_demon_edge"           "Demon Edge"
"item_desolator"            "Desolator"
"item_diffusal_blade"       "Diffusal Blade"
"item_diffusal_blade_2"     "Diffusal Blade"
"item_dust"                 "Dust of Appearance"
"item_eagle"                "Eaglesong"
"item_energy_booster"       "Energy Booster"
"item_ethereal_blade"       "Ethereal Blade"
"item_flask"                "Healing Salve"
"item_force_staff"          "Force Staff"
"item_gauntlets"            "Gauntlets of Strength"
"item_gem"                  "Gem of True Sight"
"item_ghost"                "Ghost Scepter"
"item_gloves"               "Gloves of Haste"
"item_greater_crit"         "Daedalus"
"item_hand_of_midas"        "Hand of Midas"
"item_headdress"            "Headdress"
"item_heart"                "Heart of Tarrasque"
"item_helm_of_iron_will"    "Helm of Iron Will"
"item_helm_of_the_dominator"        "Helm of the Dominator"
"item_hood_of_defiance"     "Hood of Defiance"
"item_hyperstone"           "Hyperstone"
"item_invis_sword"          "Shadow Blade"
"item_javelin"              "Javelin"
"item_lesser_crit"          "Crystalys"
"item_lifesteal"            "Morbid Mask"
"item_sphere"               "Linken's Sphere"
"item_maelstrom"            "Maelstrom"
"item_magic_stick"          "Magic Stick"
"item_magic_wand"           "Magic Wand"
"item_manta"                "Manta Style"
"item_mantle"               "Mantle of Intelligence"
"item_mask_of_madness"      "Mask of Madness"
"item_mekansm"              "Mekansm"
"item_mithril_hammer"       "Mithril Hammer"
"item_mjollnir"             "Mjollnir"
"item_monkey_king_bar"      "Monkey King Bar"
"item_mystic_staff"         "Mystic Staff"
"item_necronomicon"         "Necronomicon"
"item_necronomicon_2"       "Necronomicon"
"item_necronomicon_3"       "Necronomicon"
"item_null_talisman"        "Null Talisman"
"item_oblivion_staff"       "Oblivion Staff"
"item_ogre_axe"             "Ogre Club"
"item_orchid"               "Orchid Malevolence"
"item_pers"                 "Perseverance"
"item_phase_boots"          "Phase Boots"
"item_pipe"                 "Pipe of Insight"
"item_platemail"            "Platemail"
"item_point_booster"        "Point Booster"
"item_poor_mans_shield"     "Poor Man's Shield"
"item_power_treads"         "Power Treads"
"item_power_treads_str"     "Strength"
"item_power_treads_agi"     "Agility"
"item_power_treads_int"     "Intelligence"
"item_quarterstaff"         "Quarterstaff"
"item_quelling_blade"       "Quelling Blade"
"item_radiance"             "Radiance"
"item_rapier"               "Divine Rapier"
"item_reaver"               "Reaver"
"item_refresher"            "Refresher Orb"
"item_aegis"                "Aegis of the Immortal"
"item_cheese"               "Cheese"
"item_relic"                "Sacred Relic"
"item_ring_of_basilius"     "Ring of Basilius"
"item_ring_of_health"       "Ring of Health"
"item_ring_of_protection"   "Ring of Protection"
"item_ring_of_regen"        "Ring of Regen"
"item_robe"                 "Robe of the Magi"
"item_sange"                "Sange"
"item_sange_and_yasha"      "Sange and Yasha"
"item_satanic"              "Satanic"
"item_sheepstick"           "Scythe of Vyse"
"item_shivas_guard"         "Shiva's Guard"
"item_skadi"                "Eye of Skadi"
"item_slippers"             "Slippers of Agility"
"item_sobi_mask"            "Sage's Mask"
"item_soul_booster"         "Soul Booster"
"item_soul_ring"            "Soul Ring"
"item_staff_of_wizardry"    "Staff of Wizardry"
"item_stout_shield"         "Stout Shield"
"item_talisman_of_evasion"  "Talisman of Evasion"
"item_tango"                "Tango"
"item_tpscroll"             "Town Portal Scroll"
"item_travel_boots"         "Boots of Travel"
"item_ultimate_orb"         "Ultimate Orb"
"item_ultimate_scepter"     "Aghanim's Scepter"
"item_urn_of_shadows"       "Urn of Shadows"
"item_recipe_urn_of_shadows"    "Urn of Shadows Recipe"
"item_vanguard"             "Vanguard"
"item_vitality_booster"     "Vitality Booster"
"item_vladmir"              "Vladmir's Offering"
"item_void_stone"           "Void Stone"
"item_ward_observer"        "Observer Ward"
"item_ward_sentry"          "Sentry Ward"
"item_wraith_band"          "Wraith Band"
"item_yasha"                "Yasha"
"item_arcane_boots"         "Arcane Boots"
"item_orb_of_venom"         "Orb of Venom"
"item_ancient_janggo"       "Drum of Endurance"
"item_medallion_of_courage" "Medallion of Courage"
"item_smoke_of_deceit"      "Smoke of Deceit"
"item_veil_of_discord"      "Veil of Discord"
```